# Permanently increase file descriptor ulimit in Android without being root

Tags: android, shell, adb, file-descriptor

In my Android app, I'm encountering several problems with `Too many open files` errors.

I'm sure that there are no file descpritors leaks in my application and my current upper limit is set to 1024 opened files:

```
adb shell ulimit -a

    time(cpu-seconds)    unlimited
    file(blocks)         unlimited
    coredump(blocks)     0
    data(KiB)            unlimited
    stack(KiB)           8192
    lockedmem(KiB)       64
    nofiles(descriptors) 1024
    processes            12016
    sigpending           12016
    msgqueue(bytes)      819200
    maxnice              40
    maxrtprio            0
    resident-set(KiB)    unlimited
    address-space(KiB)   unlimited
```

I don't have root permission, so what I've tried is to increment this number with following command:

```
adb shell ulimit -n 2048
```

But limit didn't change. So I changed my user-id and retried:

```
adb shell run-as [package.name]
~ ulimit -n 2048
~ ulimit -a

    limit -a                      
    time(cpu-seconds)    unlimited
    file(blocks)         unlimited
    coredump(blocks)     0        
    data(KiB)            unlimited
    stack(KiB)           8192     
    lockedmem(KiB)       64       
    nofiles(descriptors) 2048     
    processes            12016    
    sigpending           12016    
    msgqueue(bytes)      819200   
    maxnice              40       
    maxrtprio            0        
    resident-set(KiB)    unlimited
    address-space(KiB)   unlimited
```

And I've achieved to increment this limit only for the current process. When I've restarted the app, the limit was 1024 again.

Is there another way to permanently increase this limit?

**P.S.** I searched also for `/etc/security/limits.conf` file without any luck

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `ulimit -n` to increase the maximum open files, you can use sytem api `getrlimit/setrlimit` from ndk to get or set the resource limits. You can call these apis when your app launch or during app run.

```
    struct rlimit rlm {};
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlm) < 0) {
        LOGE("getrlimit %s", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "%d %d", rlm.rlim_cur, rlm.rlim_max);
        rlm.rlim_cur = rlm.rlim_max;
        if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rlm) < 0) {
            LOGE("setrlimit %s", strerror(errno));
        }
    }
```

But you might not get good luck on those resource limit adjustment in Android, in my testing Android device, the open file current limit and maximum limit is 1024/1346 respectively. That would not get too much benefits even if you set the limit to maximum value 1346.

See more info of `getrlimit/setrlimit` from [man7](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tested two devices today, first is Google Pixel 3XL, second is Samsung s20FE.

```
    struct rlimit limit;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FDTEST", "fd limit cur=%d max=%d", limit.rlim_cur, limit.rlim_max);
```

Both reports values above 32k :

> fd limit cur=32768 max=32768

How is it possible? This is much more then 1024

Comment: Welcome to modern times. A file descriptor does I deed not eat too much space. So why shouldn't it 32k? But the total number might be smaller. Googles own LevelDb was known to run out of handles on 1024 Systems